# Powershell's Read-Host cmdlet hangs and doesn't show its prompt until I press a key?

Tags: windows, powershell, winforms, automation, ui-automation

I am trying to write a Powershell script, and part of the script requires use of the clipboard. I've run into a very strange bug where when I use Read-Host below to scan in user input, when I run the script, it prints the "Starting..." line and then hangs indefinitely. As soon as I press another key, typically right arrow, the script prints the Read-Host prompt (the "*There is already...*") and scans in input like it should. If I press a letter key instead of right arrow, the same thing happens and the letter is counted as part of user input.

The extra strange part is, this problem happens *only in this specific call* of Read-Host. I use Read-Host 2 other times in the script and those calls work just fine, printing the prompt and scanning in input immediately.

```
---just a little more code above this point, mostly just variable declarations and such---
Write-Output "Starting vfont-inator... To stop early press and hold Ctrl+C"
[Console]::Out.Flush() 
$originalX = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X
$originalY = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.Y

#move mouse to powershell window and click
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($originalX, $originalY)
[W.U32]::mouse_event(6,0,0,0,0);

#pause execution to give the user a chance to quit and save their clipboard before it is overwritten
$clipboard = Get-Clipboard
if($clipboard.Length -gt 0)
{   
   Read-Host "There is already something stored in the clipboard. This script requires using the clipboard to work, so it will overwrite anything already on the clipboard. Is this OK?`nPress Enter to overwrite the clipboard and continue, or Ctrl+C to quit the script."

}

Write-Output "Reached checkpoint 1: checked clipboard"
[Console]::Out.Flush() 
---more code below this point---
```

Things I've tried:

- Assigning the output of Read-Host to a variable, like `$input = Read-Host "There is..."`
- Adding `| FT -AutoSize` to the end of Read-Host, like I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359808/output-of-a-powershell-command-doesnt-show-result-until-after-write-host-and-re)
- Sending a right key press automatically by adding the line `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{RIGHT}")` right below Read-Host
- Adding the line `[Console]::Out.Flush()` right below Read-Host
- Changing the inside of the if statement to:

```
Write-Output "There is..."
[Console]::Out.Flush()
Read-Host " "
```

- Doing the above bulletpoint, but with `Write-Host` instead. This one I though for *sure* was gonna work, since printing to console and not a pipe is Write-Host's whole purpose. My script does not use any pipes, either.
- Giving up, accepting this function call as cursed, and so copy/pasting one of the other Read-Host statements into this line instead. (which still didn't print, so I suppose this line number is just unholy desecrated ground, regardless of its content)

Would someone please help me see why my Read-Host statement hangs until I press a key before printing its prompt and asking for input, instead of just doing so automatically right away? Using a completely different way of scanning in input would be fine as well.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I... I found the issue. I don't know how this could possibly affect it, but when I commented out the lines

```
#move mouse to powershell window and click
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($originalX, $originalY)
[W.U32]::mouse_event(6,0,0,0,0);
```

suddenly there is no more hang. I use these lines of code many many times throughout the script, and only here do they cause a problem. I have no idea what this happens or how this fixes it, but removing those two lines fixed it.

Apparently Powershell doesn't like being clicked on while running. I need a drink.